# Mongodb balancer move failed: chunk too big to move. But it's not

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I found in mongos logs:

```
[Balancer] balancer move failed: { chunkTooBig: true, estimatedChunkSize: 33972400, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "chunk too big to move" } from: rs2 to: rs3 chunk:  min: { h: 3074457345618258600 } max: { h: 3074457345618258600 }
```

~30 Megabytes. But chunk is not bigger then defined chunk size:

```
mongos> use config
switched to db config
mongos> db.settings.find({_id:"chunksize"})
{ "_id" : "chunksize", "value" : 64 }
```

Could anybody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: did you change your chunksize at any point?

Comment: I do not remember exactly, but it is possible.

Comment: in mongos shell prompt you can go to config db (via 'use config') and take a look at the db.chunks collection to see if this chunk has been labeled "jumbo" - if the chunk size used to be a lot smaller that might have happened on a failed migration.  db.chunks.find({jumbo:true}) would select all chunks labeled as "jumbo" - you can also check the mongos logs (if there aren't too many of them) to see what might have happened.

Comment: you might also look at db.collectionname.stats() - the size of chunk is determined by calculating avg doc size * number of documents - if the size varies and this shard key range (value) has disproportionately different document size the estimate may be off.

Comment: There are no jumbo chunks: mongos> use config
switched to db config
mongos> db.chunks.find({jumbo:true})
mongos>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like as known old bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9365

I have 30MB chunks about 280K docs. And mongo can not move it becouse it contain more then 250001 docs and fill error "chunk too big to move". We have situation that chuk not to big to split, and "not to small" to move.

I reproduced that localy. I created collection of 1 chunk with 36b docs (8.58MiB per chunk). If docs is 250001 or less chunk moved manualy as expected. If docs 250002 or more I got a error "chunk too big to move". Chunk size in settings 64MB.

**Work arround:**

If you planed use collection with small docs - pre-split collection so that the documents were less then 250K.